# Location of org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.deploy.DeploymentManager;

Tags: java, jar, jboss5.x

Does anyone know where this org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.deploy.DeploymentManager is located ? Which .jar do I have to add to my build path? (I've looked in a lot of .jar's so far and didn't find it.)

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its here, JBoss5.1\client\jboss-integration.jar